# I want to send mail through my Php dependibng upon what the user selects on the dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts, contact-form

I want to send my mail depending upon the option chosen by the user on the dropdown menu here's my `php` code

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
if ($dropdown = choose) {
    alert("Hover and click on the images to connect with them.");
  } elseif ($dropdown = help) {
    $recipient = "helpme@mailid.com";
  } elseif ($dropdown = suscribe) {
    $recipient = "suscribe@mailid.com";
  } elseif ($dropdown = other) {
    $recipient = "contactus@id.com";
  }

$subject = "Message From Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='http://website.com/' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

and this is my `HTML` code

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  <div class="contact-form">
    <form id="contact" action="maif.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <fieldset>
            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required="">
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <fieldset>
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required="">
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          <fieldset>
            <select name="dropdown" size="1" type="dropdown" class="form-control" id="dropdown" required="">
              <option value="choose">-- Please choose a subject of contact --</option>
              <option value="help">You need someone to talk </option>
              <option value="suscribe">Suscribe to our mailing list</option>
              <option value="other">other</option>
            </select>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <fieldset>
            <textarea name="message" rows="6" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" required=""></textarea>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <fieldset>
            <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="main-button">Send Message</button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And which part of this is not working? Is it the E-mail part? If yes, it could be anything from the mime to the pear, it'd be impossible to tell. Are you getting any errors thrown back at you? Also, your `if()` statements are all using the wrong *operator* to perform comparisons. `==` is a comparison operator, `===` is a strict, literal comparison operator checking for both value AND the data type. Furthermore, you are performing checks against what is syntactically a `superglobal`. Where are these defined? Or did you forget to use quotes to make them into strings? or put `$` in front of them?

Comment: 1) Make sure your `POST` variables contains your desired data and aren't in fact empty. 2) Fix your `if()` statements. Other than that, it's hard to tell what could be wrong without any further information.

Comment: @Martin the Error I'm getting is this....." This page isn’t working3dyfgroup.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Check 1) that the request you're making is to a valid file. Check the path etc. 2) Make sure that you're not attempting a HTTP request on a HTTPS connection or vise versa.

Comment: @Martin I don't think there is any problem with the HTTP requests because the code is working perfectly when I've only 1 `$reciepent` in my mail ... problems raised when I tried  to ad If elseif to add different recipients